# Chaining multiple observables and reusing results of already executed ones in the chain

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to combine the following functions `a()`, `b()` and `c()` to get one result.

```js
function a() {
    return rx.of(42);
}

function b(value) {
    return rx.of(value*2);
}

function c(val1, val2) {
    return rx.of({
        original: val1,
        modified: val2
    })
}
```

These are simplified variants - they would actually be HTTP-requests. The result of `a` is needed for executing `b`, `a` and `b`s results are preconditions for executing `c`. The only thing I can think of is just wrapping them all in `.subscribe()` calls, but that just doesn't look right. Yet I cannot think of a better way to solve this:

```js
// bad
new Observable(observer => {
    a().subscribe(
        result_a => {
            b(result_a).subscribe(
                result_b => {
                    c(result_a, result_b).subscribe(
                        result_c => {
                            observer.next(c);
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )    
}).subscribe(
    result => console.log(result)
)
```

I do know that there are operators such as `pipe`, `concat` and more but I do not know how to apply them in this specific situation where the result of one `Observable` is still needed for another one that is executed later on. How could I simplify this by using the proper RxJS techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is something like this, comments are added inline

```
a().pipe(
  // concatMap ensures that the order of notification is maintained, i.e. a() emits its next value only after b() has finished processing the previous one
  concatMap(valA => b(valA).pipe(
    // via this map we can return both the result of b() and also the parameter received, i.e. the result of a()
    map(valB => {
       return {valA, valB}
    })
  ),
  // here again, with concatMap, we ensure the order of notification is maintained
  concatMap(({valA, valB}) => c(valA, valB))
)
```

This is a typical pattern that may be encountered many times while using RxJS with http.

If you want to see some more of such patterns, you can read [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Answer (score 1):

The direct equivalent of your example there would be with `mergeMap`:

```ts
a().pipe(
  mergeMap(a =>
    b(a).pipe(
      mergeMap(b => c(a, b))
    )
  )
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

If order is important (once these are something that is asynchronous and not just made with `of`), then you will want to use `concatMap` instead. But the overall structure is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Given the `a` and `b` observables complete, you could use the `forkJoin` operator like this:

```js
const { of, forkJoin } = rxjs;
const { mergeMap } = rxjs.operators;

function a() {
    return of(42);
}

function b(value) {
    return of(value*2);
}

function c(val1, val2) {
    return of({
        original: val1,
        modified: val2
    })
}

const init = a();

forkJoin(
    init, 
    init.pipe(mergeMap(b))
).pipe(mergeMap(([a, b]) => c(a, b)))
.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```